# ¿Cómo se mapea y se observa un POJO simple (no una lista, array o colección) usando Retrofit en Android (Java, no Kotlin)?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, mvvm, rxjava

Estoy intentando adaptar mi código según los [Componentes de Arquitectura de Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture): patrón MVVM, LiveData, Room para la base de datos, Retrofit para los datos remotos, etc.

Para ello estoy haciendo pruebas con [este repositorio](https://github.com/abhinav0612/Pokemon)<sup>1</sup> que está escrito en Java (casi todos los ejemplos y tutoriales están basados en Kotlin y mi proyecto está en Java). Yo quiero usar también [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=es-419) para la inyección de dependencias, y el contenido en Java escasea, por lo que el código de ejemplo señalado antes me está siendo de gran ayuda en este nuevo universo.

[En el ejemplo del `ViewModel`](https://github.com/abhinav0612/Pokemon/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pokemon/viewmodel/PokemonViewModel.java) todos los objetos que se obtienen **están basados en listas**, pero yo necesito hacer un mapeo no basado en listas. Mi aplicación en muchos casos consume datos simples, no listas, por tanto yo quiero hacer un mapeo simple: **obtener un objeto concreto, mapearlo al modelo y mostrarlo en un `TextView`**.

Todos los ejemplos que he visto hasta ahora se basan en listas y se presentan casi siempre en RecyclerView usando adaptadores. Pero en mi caso no uso adaptadores, porque son objetos simples que luego yo desgloso y presento en un `TextView` (ya tengo el modelo de datos diseñado para ello).

Mi problema aquí es que yo intento obtener un objeto simple y no funciona.

#### ViewModel

```
public class ComentarioViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "ComentarioViewModel";
    private ComentarioRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<Comentario> mComentario = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @ViewModelInject
    public ComentarioViewModel(ComentarioRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public LiveData<Comentario> getComentario() {
        return repository.getComentario();
    }

    public void insertComentario(Comentario comentario){
        repository.insertComentario(comentario);
    }
    public void deleteComentario(int comentarioId){
        repository.deleteComentario(comentarioId);
    }

}
```

#### Respositorio

```
public class ComentarioRepository {

    private ComentarioDao comentarioDao;
    private ComentarioApiService apiService;

    @Inject
    public ComentarioRepository(ComentarioDao comentarioDao, ComentarioApiService apiService) {
        this.comentarioDao = comentarioDao;
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }

    public LiveData<Comentario> getComentario(){
        return apiService.getComentario();
    }

    public void insertComentario(Comentario comentario){
        comentarioDao.insertComentario(comentario);
    }

    public void deleteComentario(int comentarioId){
        comentarioDao.deleteComentario(comentarioId);
    }

    public void deleteAll(){
        comentarioDao.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

#### Fragmento

Luego intento probar en el fragmento, pero **el código no observa nada**:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ComentarioViewModel.class);
    observeComentario();
    mViewModel.getComentario();
}

private void observeComentario() {
    Log.d(TAG,"aaaa"+mViewModel.toString());
    mViewModel.getComentario().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), comentario -> {
        mComentario = comentario;
        Log.d(TAG,"_vmComentario"+comentario.getPericopa());
    });

  }
```

Si se fijan, en `observeComentario()` yo tengo dos Logs. El primero lo puedo ver, con un objeto que sería el comentario obtenido en la llamada a la API. Pero **el segundo Log no lo veo**. El código no está entrando ahí, y según los ejemplos que he visto es desde ahí donde debo actualizar la UI.

¿Por qué mi código no observa nada? ¿Hay algo que deba corregir?

Si necesitan algún aspecto más del código lo agregaré con mucho gusto.

---

1. [Artículo](https://medium.com/swlh/mvvm-with-hilt-rxjava-3-retrofit-room-live-data-and-view-binding-8da9bb1004bf) que explica el código y [traducción en castellano](https://ichi.pro/es/mvvm-con-hilt-rxjava-3-retrofit-room-live-data-y-view-binding-155760127378623).

Comment: Si ese es tu viewModel completo, el liveData que observas está vacío. Falta un método en el viewmodel que conecte el LiveData con el repositorio. El primer log se imprime porque no proviene del liveData. Si muestras tu repositorio puedo escribir una respuesta

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem gracias por tu interés. He editado la pregunta agregando el ViewModel completo.

Comment: Bien, nada inusual en el fragment o viewModel (excepto que sobra esta línea `mViewModel.getComentario();` en `onViewCreated`). El problema tiene que estar más arriba, muestra ComentarioRepository

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem repositorio agregado.

Comment: Ok, ahora hay algo sospechoso. El viewModel y el repositorio no eran más que un puente entre el fragment y ComentarioApiService que supongo es la interfaz para retorfit. Viendo que el return type de `apiService.getComentario()` es `LiveData<Comentario>` puedo suponer que no has hecho un mapeo y que `Comentario` en realidad es un ComentarioResponse. De todos modos deberías poder observarlo. La conclusión es que no están saliendo las http requests aunque es raro que no te muestre ningún error. Agregaste los permisos de internet?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem la App tiene los permisos de internet. De hecho funciona para la petición del código original (los Pokémon son traídos de una API remota). De hecho no logro entender dónde encaja `ComentarioResponse` para mi caso (sospecho incluso que no es necesario porque no estoy pidiendo una lista). Realmente hasta ahora he usado Volley para peticiones remotas, no tengo ninguna experiencia con Retrofit. Creo que como dices el problema está en el mapeo pero no veo la forma de hacerlo.

Comment: En ese caso el mapeo lo haría automaticamente el converter con el que hayas configurado retrofit. Sólo asegurate de que los nombres de las propiedades coincidan con los del json en tu respuesta. Muestra Comentario, ComentarioApiService y el provider que usa hilt pata inyectarlo. O si puedes compartir tu proyecto en github, mucho mejor.